# Same CSS selector used twice

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

As I'm going through a [CSS tutorial](https://github.com/wesbos/JavaScript30/blob/master/03%20-%20CSS%20Variables/index-FINISHED.html) I noticed the following CSS  duplicate selectors:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background: #193549;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'helvetica neue', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

Is there any benefit to putting some CSS properties in a separate CSS selector? What's the author trying to achieve?

Comment: If they are on the same file, no, there's no difference/benefit. However, if placed in separate files, they could have different effects in different pages.

Comment: in this case, they are in the same file, right next to each other, as pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No benefit, aside from personal preference. For example, grouping things together that go together so it's easier to read or update/remove. You may have your default `body` styles, then some unique styles for `body` that you added to support a plugin or something, so you might have a separate entry for `body` for the unique plugin styles that you group with other styles defined for the plugin so it's easier to read/find the styles that pertain to the plugin.

It's also bad practice to write CSS like that. It uses extra space (making your files bigger) and makes cleanup and tracking down style changes more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The class properties should be consolidated for better maintenance and consistency.

Answer (score 0):

There are no advantages to having multiple CSS blocks like that. It may cause heartache later on if they are in different files because the last property listed will "win".

So if the second `body` also has `text-align` property, the second one will "overwrite" the first one.

In any case, if it is the same selector, they should be in the same CSS block.